# Defining a Subclass (c++)

Tags: c++, subclass

I want to define a subclass 'B' of a class 'A' so I can call different functions with the same name using a subclass of the main class. 'B' does not actually have to do store anything other than functions.

I get the following error:

```
error: use of non-static data member 'bar' of 'A' from nested type 'B'
bar = 2;
```

I understand this is because the class B does not know anything about the variables from A unless it is given an instance of A. How would I do this in the following code such that B knows about A's variables?

CODE:

A.h:

```
class A{
   public:
   int foo();

   class B{
       public:
       int foo();
   }

   private:
   int bar;
}
```

A.cpp

```
A::A(){
bar = 1;
}

A::foo(){
return bar;
}

A::B::foo(){
bar = 2;
return bar;
}
```

Main Program:

```
int main(){
  A a;
  std::cout<<a.foo()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<a.B.foo()<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class `A::B` doesn't have a member named `bar`. Also `a.B` is meaningless, as `B` is not a data member of `A`. You seem to believe there's some magical connection between instances of `A` and instances of `A::B`; there's none such. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: B isn't a subclass of A. class B (the type) is declared inside (the declaration of) A; this is usually done with helper classes, to hide them from users of A.

Comment: "so I can call different functions with the same name" this is a bogus reason

Comment: can you give a example that is a bit more concrete? The question isnt that clear, because if what you actually want is a subclass, then neither your implementation is correct nor would you be able to call a method of the subclass as `a.B.foo()`

Comment: Were you perhaps thinking of inheritance, in the form of `class B : public A`, where `B` is an extension of `A` and implicitly has all the members of an `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to `A::bar` in `A::B::foo` is not allowed in C++.
It would be allowed in Java to my knowledge